# Accessing phpmyadmin in Nginx directly from IP address (without a subdomain)

Tags: nginx, subdomain, url, phpmyadmin, documentroot

In an Ubuntu 16.04 Nginx environment which has some sites working fine, I've installed phpmyadmin:

```
cd /var/www/html
wget https://www.phpmyadmin.net/downloads/phpMyAdmin-latest-all-languages.zip
find ./ -type f -iname '*phpmyadmin*.zip' -exec unzip {} \;
find ./ -type d -iname 'phpmyadmin-*' -exec mv {} phpmyadmin \;
```

I then tried to access it from my browser via `ip_address/phpmyadmin`, yet I got a 404 in one of my sites.

I thought this is caused from lacking a webapp conf so I created one.

`nano /etc/nginx/sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf`:

```
server {
    root /var/www/html/phpmyadmin/;
    server_name phpmyadmin;

    location / {
        index index.php index.html index.htm fastcgi_index;
        try_files $uri $uri =404 $uri/ /index.php?$args;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php7.0-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
        include fastcgi_params;
    }

    listen 80;
}
```

Then

```
ln -s /etc/nginx/sites-available/phpmyadmin.conf /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/
systemctl restart nginx.service
```

Yet, the problem persist.

The logs specify only this error:

> 2018/01/01 03:02:25 [emerg] 21959#21959: unknown directive
>   "/var/www/html/phpmyadmin/" in
>   /etc/nginx/sites-enabled/phpmyadmin.conf:2

I basically didn't change `nginx.conf` and rely on its native directives.

I have consulted an Nginx sysadmin how suggested me to use a subdomain but I prefer accessing it directly from IP address.

Comment: This is the third or fourth question on this topic in the past couple of weeks. I had a quick look and can't find them quickly. Short answer: accessing a server by IP addresses is problematic or perhaps not possible if it's serving another site by domain. Take the advise of the Nginx sysadmin and myself, use a subdomain.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `server_name` should contain the name(s) used to access the server. To access a server by IP address, it should contain the IP address.

For example:

```
server_name 192.0.2.1;
```

See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/server_names.html#miscellaneous_names) for more.

**But first you need to fix that error** - I don't know why you are getting an *unknown directive* error from your `root` statement. Have you introduced a typo?

Comment: Thanks Richard. `server_name 192.0.2.1 phpmyadmin;` did work. There was a typo (redundant space) now fixed.

Comment: Related: https://serverfault.com/questions/888702/duplicated-version-of-a-local-wordpress-site-isnt-available-online-in-an-ngin